# How to get data from resposne in next concatMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is a rxjs stream that load data by id then types from server:

```
  this.applicationSubjectRepository
            .getZagsDoc(appsubjectid)
            .pipe(
                indicate(this.loading$),
                observableTimestampResponse(),
                concatMap(() => this.applicationSubjectRepository.getZagsDocType()),
                switchMap((subjecttypes) =>
                    this.dialog
                        .open(DialogSubjectsSubdocumentsComponent, {
                            ...this.dialogConfig,
                            data: { mode: MODES.CREATE, subjecttypes, appsubjectid: appsubjectid },
                        })
                        .afterClosed()
                        .pipe(
                            filter(Boolean),
                            concatMap(() => this.applicationSubjectRepository.getByAppSubjectId(PASS_HERE)),
                        ),
                ),
            )
            .subscribe((subjectdocuments: any[]) => {
                this.subject.zagsdocs = subjectdocuments;
            });
```

How to pass response from `.getZagsDoc(appsubjectid)` to `getByAppSubjectId(PASS_HERE)` instead `PASS_HERE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you lost the value of `this.applicationSubjectRepository.getZagsDoc(appsubjectid)` by the line

```
concatMap(() => this.applicationSubjectRepository.getZagsDocType()),
```

you can avoid this:

```
concatMap((zagsDoc) => this.applicationSubjectRepository.getZagsDocType().pipe(map(x => ([zagsDoc, x])))),
```

Comment: So, you offer to use map to return current values and prev?

Comment: Why `[zagsDoc, x]` instead `{zagsDoc, x}`?

Comment: "So, you offer to use map to return current values and prev?" - correct
"Why [zagsDoc, x] instead {zagsDoc, x}" - this is up to you, i prefer arrays